# NumPy element-wise multiplication with arrays of different dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm struggling with finding out how to do element-wise multiplication of a three-dimensional array with a two-dimensional array such that every vector in the three-dimensional array is multiplied with the scalar found in the two-dimensional array with the same index.

```
dist = np.array([[0.2, 0.3], [0.4,0.5], [0.6, 0.7], [0.8,0.9]])
a = np.array([[0.1, 1, 2, 3],[1,0.1,4,5],[2,4,0.1,6],[3,5,6,0.1]])
b = np.array([[[0,0], [-0.2,-0.2], [-0.4,-0.4], [-0.6,-0.6]], [[0.2,0.2], [0,0], [-0.2,-0.2], [-0.4,-0.4]], [[0.4,0.4], [0.2,0.2], [0,0], [-0.2,-0.2]],[[0.6,0.6], [0.4,0.4], [0.2,0.2], [0,0]]])
print(a)
print(b, end='\n\n')

print(np.matmul(a,b), end='\n\n')
print(np.multiply(a,b))
```

In the example above, *dist* is a matrix of points, *a* is a symmetrical matrix of points, and *b* is a matrix where each value is a row from the dist array subtracted with another. Thus b[0,0] is (element wise) dist[0]-dist[0], b[0,1] is dist[0]-dist[1], b[1,0] = dist[1]-dist[0].

What I'm looking for is an outputted array 'c' where the element c[i,j] is (element wise) a[i,j]*b[i,j]. Thus c[0,0] would in this example be [0,0], and c[1,2] would be [-0.8,-0.8], etc. I guess I could do it as a *for* loop, but since I'm planning on using this in a function that iterates thousands of times I would rather not.

I couldn't get any search engine to understand what I was looking for, so I thought I might ask you fellow humans. Also: simple explanations would be awesome since I for the most part barely know what I'm doing.

Comment: `a` is (4,4), `b` is (2,4,2) shape?  Often it helps to demonstrate with the loop.  Code, even if slower, is less ambiguous than words.  Learning by 'search engine` is not as good as actually reading the basic numpy documentation.

Comment: Did you get errors with the 2 things you tried?  Learn anything from them?

Answer (score 2):

Adding an extra dimension for the two-dimensional array should work.

```
import numpy as np

dist = np.array([[0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5], [0.6, 0.7], [0.8, 0.9]])
a = np.array([[0.1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 0.1, 4, 5], [2, 4, 0.1, 6], [3, 5, 6, 0.1]])
b = np.array([[[0, 0], [-0.2, -0.2], [-0.4, -0.4], [-0.6, -0.6]], [[0.2, 0.2], [0, 0], [-0.2, -0.2], [-0.4, -0.4]], [[0.4, 0.4], [0.2, 0.2], [0, 0], [-0.2, -0.2]], [[0.6, 0.6], [0.4, 0.4], [0.2, 0.2], [0, 0]]])

a = a[:, :, np.newaxis]

c = a * b

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[[  0.   0. ]
[   -0.2 -0.2]
[   -0.8 -0.8]
[   -1.8 -1.8]] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

dist = np.array([[0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5], [0.6, 0.7], [0.8, 0.9]])
b = np.array([[[0,0], [-0.2,-0.2], [-0.4,-0.4], [-0.6,-0.6]],
              [[0.2,0.2], [0,0], [-0.2,-0.2], [-0.4,-0.4]],
              [[0.4,0.4], [0.2,0.2], [0,0], [-0.2,-0.2]],
              [[0.6,0.6], [0.4,0.4], [0.2,0.2], [0,0]]])

# Reshape the dist array to match the shape of b
dist_reshaped = dist.reshape((4, 1, 2))

# Perform element-wise multiplication
result = b * dist_reshaped

print(result)
```

In your case, you have a 3D array, *b*, and a 2D array *dist*, and you want to multiply each 2D slice of the 3D array b with the corresponding scalar value from the 2D array dist
eshape the dist array to have a shape of (4, 1, 2), so that it can broadcast along the first dimension when performing element-wise multiplication with the 3D array b. Then, the element-wise multiplication is done, resulting in the desired output where each 2D slice of the 3D array b is multiplied by the corresponding scalar from the 2D array dist.

The result array will contain the element-wise products between b and dist, and it will have the same shape as the original b array: (4, 4, 2)

Comment: Was this generated by [some tool](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)?

Comment: What is *"dist eshape"*?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample arrays shapes:

```
In [211]: a.shape
Out[211]: (4, 4)

In [212]: b.shape
Out[212]: (4, 4, 2)
```

`matmul/@` does run, with a shape that matches `b`, summed some products.  That is not 'element-wise':

```
In [213]: np.matmul(a,b)
Out[213]: 
array([[[-2.8 , -2.8 ],
        [-4.62, -4.62],
        [-4.44, -4.44],
        [-3.46, -3.46]],

       [[-1.58, -1.58],
        [-2.6 , -2.6 ],
        [-2.02, -2.02],
        [-0.64, -0.64]],

       [[-0.36, -0.36],
        [-0.58, -0.58],
        [ 0.4 ,  0.4 ],
        [ 2.18,  2.18]],

       [[ 0.86,  0.86],
        [ 1.44,  1.44],
        [ 2.82,  2.82],
        [ 5.  ,  5.  ]]])

In [214]: _.shape
Out[214]: (4, 4, 2)
```

Plain multiply/* does not run because of mismatch in shapes:

```
In [215]: np.multiply(a,b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[215], line 1
----> 1 np.multiply(a,b)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,4) (4,4,2)
```

But making `a` to be (4,4,1), lets it match (4,4,2) shaped `b`:

```
In [216]: np.multiply(a[:,:,None],b)
Out[216]: 
array([[[ 0. ,  0. ],
        [-0.2, -0.2],
        [-0.8, -0.8],
        [-1.8, -1.8]],

       [[ 0.2,  0.2],
        [ 0. ,  0. ],
        [-0.8, -0.8],
        [-2. , -2. ]],

       [[ 0.8,  0.8],
        [ 0.8,  0.8],
        [ 0. ,  0. ],
        [-1.2, -1.2]],

       [[ 1.8,  1.8],
        [ 2. ,  2. ],
        [ 1.2,  1.2],
        [ 0. ,  0. ]]])

In [217]: _.shape
Out[217]: (4, 4, 2)
```

We could iterate on the last dim of `b` to get the same thing:

```
In [220]: np.stack([a*b[:,:,i] for i in range(2)], axis=-1)
Out[220]: 
array([[[ 0. ,  0. ],
        [-0.2, -0.2],
        [-0.8, -0.8],
        [-1.8, -1.8]],
...])
```

With 3d arrays, the `matmul` calculation takes a little more work to understand.  It's equivalent to:

```
In [221]: np.einsum('ij,kjl',a,b).shape
Out[221]: (4, 4, 2)
```

where `j` is the sum-of-products dimension.